# When is using definite article `el` necessary (or optional)?

Tags: traducción

Supposedly, the correct translation from English

```
Is soccer fun?
```

is

```
El fútbol es divertido?
```

Another example was

```
Mr. Perez.
```

translated to

```
El señor Perez.
```

But also, sometimes `el` supposedly (deemed by some language learning app) isn't correct? For example, the following `Mr.` shouldn't be accompanied by a definite article `El`:

```
Mr. Albert, see you later!
Señor Albert, ¡hasta luego!
```

When is using definite article `el` necessary (or optional) in Spanish?

Comment: In the señor case, the el is used for third person and not used in second person

Answer (score 2):

Something similar happens in English when certain nouns are used as **vocatives**, that is, as a way of calling somebody's attention when speaking to them:

- **Young lady**, would you like to dance with me? => **Señorita**, ¿querría bailar conmigo? (vocative without article)
- **The young lady** did not want to dance with me => **La jovencita** no quiso bailar conmigo (common noun with article)
- **Teacher**, could you explain that again? => **Maestro/Profesor**, ¿podría volver a explicarlo? (vocative without article)
- **The teacher** did not explain clearly => **El maestro/profesor** no explicaba con claridad. (common noun with article)
- **Doctor**, please give me some medicine => **Doctor**, por favor deme un remedio. (vocative without article)
- **The doctor** did not give me any medicine => **El doctor/médico** no me dio ningún remedio. (common noun with article)